# Trouble trying to run Python 2.7 and 3.4 in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse

I've installed `Python 3.4` and am currently using `Python 2.7`. I want to create a Project in `Python 3.4`, but, when I go to Run-->Run Configurations and then look to make a new entry under Python Run , I see that C:\Python34 doesn't show up. Also, when I try to create a new Project, the "Grammar Version" goes only up to 3.0. I don't know how to resolve this.

**Edit**: Could this be because I haven't installed `Python 3.4` correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using PyDev. I don't know if there are other alternatives but that's what I use for Python in Eclipse.

1. Right-click on your project folder in the Package Explorer view and select "Properties".
2. Select "PyDev - Interpreter/Grammar"
3. Select the appropriate Grammar Version and Interpreter, if those options contain the Python version you want.
4. If not, click on "Click here to configure an interpreter not listed."
5. Click "New" and provide an interpreter name (e.g. python3.4) and path to the executable (C:\Python34)

Once you've done that, you should see the option to select your Python 3.4 interpreter under Run Configurations > Interpreter. It'll be displayed using the interpreter name you provided in step 5.